# Show new records new :id on create and then its true :id on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a simple_form that shows the what the :id of the form will be when its created using this `<%= (Invoice.last.id + 1) %>` but when I hit edit and render the form again I want to have something like this `<%= @invoice.id %>` Would an if statement be a good solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not good to assume that the new invoice id will be `Invoice.last.id + 1`. If your website has more than one user at once, then you can't predict which one will save their invoice first. So whatever invoice id you provide will at least sometimes be wrong.

Better to simply not display the id of an invoice that hasn't been created yet, like:

```
<% unless @invoice.new_record? %>
  Invoice ID: <%= @invoice.id %>
<% end %>
```

Or display a placeholder, like:

```
Invoice ID: <%= @invoice.new_record? ? 'New Invoice' : @invoice.id %>
```